# Make a list of random numbers in python without using numbers in another list

Tags: python

I am trying to make a card game and I want to  be able to generate random numbers in a list but I do not want the numbers to repeat themselves after they have been used once while the program is running.

Here is what I have so far:

```
usedcards = []
import random

def choosecards():
    global usedcards
    cards=random.sample(range(52), 5)
    usedcards = usedcards + cards
    #print(usedcards)
    return cards
```

Each time I run the function, I want the `usedcards` list to be cross checked with the cards variable.

How can I make this happen?

Comment: Just make a list of available cards, shuffle it (`random.shuffle()`) and `.pop()` a card when you need one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to do this using sets. Sets make it very easy to exclude the cards that have already been used.

```
import random

used_cards = set()

def choose_cards(n_cards):
    # No need to do 'global used_cards', used_cards is
    #    already global and can be modified inplace
    # Find the set difference between all the cards and
    #   those that have been used
    available = set(range(52)) - used_cards
    chosen = random.sample(available, n_cards)
    for card in chosen:
        used_cards.add(card)
    return chosen


for i in range(4):
    print(choose_cards(5))
    print(used_cards)
```

Comment: you can also use `used_cards.update(chosen)` to avoid the for-loop

Answer (score 3):

A generator can keep the state and hide the details:

```
import random

def choosecards(amount=5):
    cards = list(range(52))
    random.shuffle(cards)
    while True:
        yield [cards.pop() for _ in range(amount)]


>>> cards = choosecards()
>> next(cards)
[37, 41, 13, 2, 33]
>>> next(cards)
[4, 8, 7, 38, 23]
```

Answer (score 2):

don't use globals. The problem becomes easy to solve if you use parameters properly.

```
def choosecards(stack, amount=5):
    cards=[ stack.pop() for i in range(amount) ]
    return cards


deck = list(range(52))
random.shuffle(deck)
hand = choosecards(deck)
otherhand = choosecards(deck)
#etc.
```

Comment: I think you mean `stack.pop()`